# How to read a compressed Spark eventLog?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lz4

When I try to read a Spark 2.4.4 eventLog compressed with lz4, I obtain an empty DataFrame:

```
cd /opt/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
bin/spark-shell --master=local --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.compress=true --conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4 --driver-memory 4G --driver-library-path=/opt/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native/

// Trying to read an event log from a previous session
spark.read.option("compression", "lz4").json(s"file:///tmp/spark-events/local-1589202668377.lz4")

// res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = []
```

However it works fine when I read an uncompressed eventLog:

```
bin/spark-shell --master=local --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.compress=false
spark.read.json(s"file:///tmp/spark-events/${sc.applicationId}.inprogress").printSchema

//root
// |-- App ID: string (nullable = true)
// |-- App Name: string (nullable = true)
// |-- Block Manager ID: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- Executor ID: string (nullable = true)
```

I also tried to read an eventLog compressed with snappy, same result.

Comment: Your code sample shows that you are reading from a file "in progress" -- are you really sure that the _incomplete_ compressed file has written anything on disk yet? (you need to fill up at least 1 memory buffer before it can be flushed to disk) -- are you really sure that an _incomplete_ compressed file can be read without throwing an error and discarding whatever could be read?

Comment: In the second example (without compression), I was indeed reading an inprogress file. However in the first example I was reading a complete file that was written by a previous spark shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
spark.read.json("dbfs:/tmp/compress/part-00000.lz4")
spark.conf.set("spark.io.compression.codec","org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec")
```

If it does not works there might be a good chance that your lz4 is not compatible with `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec` 
Below is the open issue link for the same
[lz4 incompatibility between OS and Hadoop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12990)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I can see that the Spark lz4 is not compatible with the Linux one, but it should be able to read the lz4 it wrote itself? In my first example, I was reading an eventLog lz4 file that was produced by Spark.

Comment: _"Spark should be able to read the lz4 it wrote itself?"_ > not necessarily... A DataFrame is stored on a distributed filesystem (HDFS or an object store like S3 via a connector) **by the executors**, in parallel, using Hadoop libs and their native compression codecs designed originally for MapReduce. The event log is produced **by the driver** and may use a different API (e.g. a single HDFS connection on a binary file?? using the base Java compression libs?? to be verified in the source code...)

Answer (score 1):

I can actually decompress the file first, using the Spark codec, and then read the decompressed file:

```
import java.io.{FileInputStream, FileOutputStream}
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec

val inFile = "/tmp/spark-events/local-1589202668377.lz4"
val outFile = "/tmp/spark-events/local-1589202668377" 
val codec = new LZ4CompressionCodec(sc.getConf)
val is = codec.compressedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile))
val os = new FileOutputStream(outFile)
IOUtils.copyLarge(is, os)
os.close()
is.close()

spark.read.json(outFile).printSchema
```

It would be nicer if I could directly read the `inFile` without using a temporary storage, but at least I can get access to the data.